# Why does my NodeJS Server make clients download the files?

Tags: node.js, express

I am using Express and NodeJS to create an API. But when I finished coding it, I opened the index, and instead of rendering the index file, it just made me download it. I could not find any errors causing this. Here is my code:

```
app.get("/", function(req,res){
  res.render("index", {name:auth.name})
}
```

The definition of app is `express()`, auth is SQLite DBWrapper

Comment: There's relevant context missing from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are either 3 scenarios:

1. The file type is not recognizable (or the mime type) and so the server will think that the file is supposed to be downloaded (that is very unlikely because express is supposed to recognize .pug files)
2. You did not `app.use` the pug parser
3. If all above are incorrect, you either did not set the MIME type properly (maybe check your code twice).

If all of those are incorrect, maybe be more specific next time.